# C# modifiing Excel files, keeping the style

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I have an excel - file that works as a template for data to be generated. I need to modify this Excel-Sheet, duplicate it a few times and add data to it.

I tried using excellibrary from nuget the following way:

```
Workbook tmpl = Workbook.Load("template.xlt");
tmpl.Save("newFile.xls");
```

As you can see I do nothing at all: Just opening the Excel File and saving it under a different name. 
The Problem is:
All the content is inside the target xls, but all Styles are gone (Font sizes, Colors, etc.)

Using an XLS file instead of a xlt when loading does not change a thing.

Is there a way to solve this or another library that works better?

Comment: Have you tried the OpenXML SDK library from Microsoft? It allows you to do about anything you want with the newer xlsx files (Excel 2007 and newer) in C#

Comment: @dave823 OpenXML works just fine (at least what my first tests indicate). Make this an answer and I will select it. Thx. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the OpenXML SDK from Microsoft. It allows you to do about anything with the newer xlsx files (Excel 2007 and up) using C#.

[OpenXML SDK for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)  this one gives you the ability to serve the Temple structure. i was having problem with the template editing i solved by sing this. this might help you.

for more help about this you can view [Create excel file](http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another Library you can Try is ClosedXML, in my experience it makes it very easy to manipulate Excel documents.